# Python & SQLalchemy (ORM): How mapping `None` to a special value like Zero or empty String for `NOTNULL` Columns to make them UNIQUE

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, nullable

Assuming you want to make one or more comuns `UNIQUE` or want to make an `INDEX`. This only works in MySQL (maybe also in other DB, i do not know) if all columns are set to `NOTNULL == True`. But the Colums must be nullable. From what I read you should assingn a *special value*, which will represent NULL. The *special value* could be `0` (Zero) or `""` (empty String). Of course this value is not then allowed as an standard assignement (there is no representation for `0` or `""` in the Column anymore)

If I use an ORM like SQLalchemy to access my DB in python it would be more comfortable to convert the *special value* to `None` on reading from DB and back to *special value* if you set the column to `None`.

Actual I think the best solution is to use getters and setters like that:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class NotNullClass(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'notnull_class'

    id = Column(INTEGER , primary_key=True)
    _column1 = Column('column1', INTEGER, nullable=False, unique=True)

    @hybrid_property
    def column1(self):
        if (_column1 == 0):
            return None
        else
            return _column1

    @column1.setter
    def column1(self, value):
        if (value == 0):
            raise Exception
        elif (value == None)
            _column1 = 0
        else
            _column1 = value
```

But is there a better solution, like an build-in property in SQLalchemy? Or is there another best practise?